# How do I bind apps to specific tags in dwm?

Tags: window-manager, workspaces, dwm

I am using dwm with tags labelled with `font-awesome` icons. I don't know how to bind applications to specific tags, e.g `Sublime` to tag 3. I've attached my tag setup in the image

[image: these are my all 5 tags]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new entry to the `rules` array in the `config.h`.

Here's a good explanation on the Gentoo Linux wiki: [dwm - assigning applications to window tags](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Dwm#Assigning_applications_to_window_tags)

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `config.h` file. See https://dwm.suckless.org/customisation/rules/ and https://dwm.suckless.org/customisation/tagmask/